# Android soporta codificación SHA2-256?

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación que por parte del servidor están utilizando SHA2-256 en las respuestas de un API. No encuentro claramente la forma de codificar y decodificar estas cadenas con codificación SHA2-256. Me podrían explicar si Android tiene soporte para esto y si pueden, funciones ejemplo para codificar y decodificar.

Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No puedes codificar y decodificar al convertir una cadena a SHA ya que para obtener un hash se realiza mediante un proceso unidireccional, es decir se calcula en una dirección y no se puede decodificar de vuelta, por lo tanto no es un tipo de codificación.**

> Los algoritmos de hash criptográficos producen hashes **irreversibles y
>   únicos.** Significado irreversible de que si solo tuviera el hash, no
>   podría usarlo para descubrir cuál era el dato original, por lo tanto,
>   permitiría que los datos originales permanecieran seguros y
>   desconocidos.

Android puede convertir una cadena a un hash SHA-256 (Que en realidad es un SHA-2), este es un ejemplo:

```
public static String getSHA256(String message){    
    String result = null;
    try {
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        digest.reset();
        digest.update(message.getBytes("utf8"));
        result = String.format("%064x", new BigInteger(1, digest.digest()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Muchas, gracias! Me sirvió mucho tu respuesta!